# Move from paralellshel to npm-run-all package

Tags: npm, package.json

The NPM Package [Paralellshell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallelshell) is no longer compatible with the latest node version so I want to move to [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) as [suggested by the develope](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/issues/10)r.

I have this line in my package.json which I execute with `npm run dev`:

```
"watch:js": "webpack --config path/webpack.dev.config.js",
"watch:css": "watch \"npm run build:dev:css\" path/scss",
"dev": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:css\" \"npm run watch:js\"",
```

Now how would I write this command with [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all)?

I simply tried to write:

```
"dev": "npm-run-all \"npm run watch:css\" \"npm run watch:js\"",
```

But this throws the error:

> mac:folder user$ npm run dev
>
> folder@0.0.0 dev /path
>
> npm-run-all "npm run watch:css" "npm run watch:js"
>
> ERROR: Task not found: "npm"

I'm a bit out of my water here. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the [`--parallel`](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/blob/HEAD/docs/npm-run-all.md#run-scripts-in-parallel) option to run both `watch:css` and `watch:js` in parallel..

For instance:

```json
"dev": "npm-run-all --parallel watch:css watch:js"
```